# requirejs anonymous dependency not defined

Tags: javascript, requirejs, dependencies

I have a problem with requirejs and a dependency being undefined.

My setup is the following:

```
var lib = function (){...};

define(function() {
    return lib;
});
```

And the modules are define like this

```
var mod = function (){
   ...
   lib('para') ...
};

define(["lib/lib"], function(lib) {
    return mod;
});
```

In my main.js I have this

```
require(['lib/lib'], function(lib){
   lib('para').mod();
})
```

**The Problem:** Lib is available in main.js but for mod I get an error Uncaught `ReferenceError: lib is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the actual problem was that everything was within an IIFE. This leads to `define` not being available, which leads to the If clause resolving in the else part.

`Window.define` is available however, so passing this to the IIFE solves my issue.