# Why is define undefined in a module using requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, undefined, requirejs-define

I use requirejs, I have this script tag

```
<script data-main="{{asset('/libs/js/main')}}" src="{{asset('/libs/js/requirejs/require.js')}}"></script>
```

In my main.js I load this

```
require(['test'], function(_){
  ...
})
```

In the main.js define is defined.

My test.js looks like this

```
(function(){
  console.log(define);
  ...
}());
```

But inside the test.js if I run this `console.log(define)` I get undefined. Why, shouldn'T define be defined? The actual defining works like a charm, no errors. Scripts are loading.

Comment: possible duplicate of [requirejs anonymous dependency not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24079202/requirejs-anonymous-dependency-not-defined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the problem was, that everything was within an IIFE. Removing this solved my problem.

EDIT: Now that I understand the problem, it is a duplicate of this one.

[requirejs anonymous dependency not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24079202/requirejs-anonymous-dependency-not-defined)